# How to unstack a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to programming languages. I am trying pandas and python. I have a `csv` file that I want to turn the table. The original table looks like:

```
    W0  W1  W2
P1  11  12  10
P2   7   6   3
P3   7  11   8
P4  12   8  13
P5   8   5  13
```

I want to turn the table so that the P1-Pn would be my first row and W0-Wn be my column.
I tried several codes but none worked.

Comment: There is an unstack function in pandas, maybe you can take a look at it?

Comment: I tried unstack but I am doing something wrong because it only pivots W0 not the whole row

Comment: Can you post your expect output. Also, use `df.head().to_dict()` to provide some initial data for testing.

Comment: Actually Grr answered my question. You can see my expected output in his answer.

Comment: Sure thing. Please do accept Grr's answer by clicking the check mark. Do provide some input and output next time you ask a question to help us and thus help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.

If you mean you want the `P` values as the Columns and `W` values as index you can transpose the dataframe:

```
df.T
    P1  P2  P3  P4  P5
W0  11   7   7  12   8
W1  12   6  11   8   5
W2  10   3   8  13  13
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I wanted to do